# How to re-display a div after the button that hid it is hidden?

Tags: javascript, css, button, hide, show

How would you display a div/class that has already been hidden by a button after said button has been hidden due to screen resolution css using `@media`. This is the code for the button:

```
<script>
var button = document.getElementById('answer'); 

function showDiv() {
  var div = document.getElementById('displayfilter');

  if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the css for the screen res;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1026px) {

  .displayfilter {
    display: none;
  }

  .answer {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

The above works fine until the screen is returned to normal size. Thanks!

Comment: You sir, are hereby granted the "most confusing question that is grammatically correct" award!

Comment: It was very difficult to put to words! Haha apologies..

Comment: How about you tell us the expected behavior? As it stands, we can only guess what you are intending to do.

Comment: There should be a badge for this. Anyway : @Midas, the answer lies in your use case. How do actually want the user to make the div visible again ? After a period of time ? By clicking somewhere ?

Comment: The way I realised this issue was when I made the page res smaller as if using on a mobile and then made back to normal. What I would like it to do is when the page is back to normal size it will display the "displayfilter" regardless if it was hidden or not

Comment: Please think about what you want first, then look for a solution. It seems you are doing it the other way around right now.

Comment: Should that panel be visible by default on mobile? Should it have the ability to toggle the visibility on mobile?

Comment: @seemly the button should be visible by default, and I want it to toggle the div to display AND when the browser resizes the div to display regardless if it was hidden by the button or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly the question, if the page is resized wider than 1026 and the div is hidden then show it:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

  if (window.innerWidth > 1026 && div.style.display == 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }

};
```

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do, do I need to change the div for it to work?

Comment: You should assign the variable outside of the showDiv() function so it can be used in other functions, like in this one.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alvaro worked perfectly. Glad you could understand my confusing question!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the div by default on large screens you need to take the `displayfilter` class and add `display:block;` to it but outside of the media query, like so:

```
.displayfilter {
    display: block;
}
```

At the moment you are saying **If [device width] is less than or equal to [specified #], then do {...}.** Your specified device width being **1026px.** You are not telling the stylesheet to display it by default so it is not being displayed.

Comment: It already displays by default, but what I mean is, if the button hides it and then the screen resizes it the button will hide but then the "displayfilter" is still hidden

Comment: @Midas It sounds like you need something else to get the div to appear again, for example another button to trigger the div and display it again. Do you want the button to display when the screen resizes without any input from the user?

Comment: No just the div not the button